# how to convert a list into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
rows =[]
for dt in new_info:
    x =  dt['state']
    est = dt['estimates']

    col_R = [val['choice'] for val in est if val['party'] == 'Rep']
    col_D = [val['choice'] for val in est if val['party'] == 'Dem']

    incumb = [val['party'] for val in est if val['incumbent'] == True ]

    rows.append((x, col_R, col_D, incumb))
```

Now I want to convert my rows list into a pandas data frame. Structure of my  rows list is shown below and my list has 32 entries.

[image]

When I convert this into a pandas data frame, I get the entries in the data frame as a list. :

```
pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=["State", "R", "D", "incumbent"])
```

[image]

But I want my data frame like this

[image]

The new info variable looks like this 
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you mind the objects in the columns being lists, I would use a generator to remove the lists wrapping your items:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rows = [(u'KY', [u'McConnell'], [u'Grimes'], [u'Rep']),
        (u'AR', [u'Cotton'], [u'Pryor'], [u'Dem']),
        (u'MI', [u'Land'], [u'Peters'], [])]

def get(r, nth):
    '''helper function to retrieve item from nth list in row r'''
    return r[nth][0] if r[nth] else np.nan

def remove_list_items(list_of_records):
    for r in list_of_records:
        yield r[0], get(r, 1), get(r, 2), get(r, 3)
```

The generator works similarly to this function, but instead of materializing a list unnecessarily in memory as an intermediate step, it just passes each row that would be in the list to the consumer of the list of rows:

```
def remove_list_items(list_of_records):
    result = []
    for r in list_of_records:
        result.append((r[0], get(r, 1), get(r, 2), get(r, 3)))
    return result
```

And then compose your DataFrame passing your data through the generator, (or the list version, if you wish.)

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
        remove_list_items(rows), 
        columns=["State", "R", "D", "incumbent"])
>>> df
  State          R       D incumbent
0    KY  McConnell  Grimes       Rep
1    AR     Cotton   Pryor       Dem
2    MI       Land  Peters       NaN
```

Or you could use a list comprehension or a generator expression (shown) to do essentially the same:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
      ((r[0], get(r, 1), get(r, 2), get(r, 3)) for r in rows), 
      columns=["State", "R", "D", "incumbent"])
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69869/discussion-between-aaron-hall-and-elizabeth-susan-joseph).

Answer (score 7):

You can use some built in python list manipulation and do something like:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda i: ''.join(i))
```

which will produce:

```
    col1 col2
0    a  [d]
1    b  [e]
2    c  [f]
```

Obviously `col2` hasn't been formatted in order to show contrast.

## Edit

As requested by OP, if you want to implement an `apply(lambda...)` to all the columns then you can either explicitly set each column with a line that looks like the one above replacing `'col1'` with each of the column names you wish to alter or you can just loop over the columns like this:

if you have a data frame of type

```
x = [['a'],['b'],['c'],['d']]
y = [['e'],['f'],['g'],['h']]
z = [['i'],['j'],['k'],['l']]

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':x, 'col2':y, 'col3':z})
```

then you can loop over the columns

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda i: ''.join(i))
```

which converts a data frame that starts like:

```
   col1 col2 col3
0  [a]  [e]  [i]
1  [b]  [f]  [j]
2  [c]  [g]  [k]
3  [d]  [h]  [l]
```

and becomes

```
    col1 col2 col3
0    a    e    i
1    b    f    j
2    c    g    k
3    d    h    l
```

Comment: @ElizabethSusanJoseph does my solution not solve your problem?

Comment: but how can I apply this to my entire data frame?? can you edit your answer to my question, it would be really helpful

Comment: new_df  = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=["State", "R", "D", "incumbent"])
new_df[['R', 'D', 'incumbent']].apply(lambda i: ''.join(i)) , I am getting an error if I execute your code

Comment: Your solution is much simpler, but  I am getting an value error  "all arrays must be of same length". Here is the entire code version : https://bpaste.net/show/76cb1f8d3036

Comment: @ElizabethSusanJoseph that means that your columns do not all have the same length when trying to construct the data frame. You can use my implementation after you have constructed the data frame that contains the entries as lists (your first data frame image in the original question) and THEN loop over the columns to convert from lists to a string values.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sure I will implement this.

Comment: @ElizabethSusanJoseph don't forget to up-vote or accept the solution if it's the one used to solve your question.